# How do I skip over an input when tabbing through a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that looks like this, for aesthetic reasons:

```
<-------input1--------> <--submit-->

<------------input2---------------->
```

When the user is on input1 and presses 'tab' they should go to input2, and when they are on input2 and press 'shift+tab' they should go to input1, all while being able to press enter to submit the form. Is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to modify the `tabindex` attribute on the elements to the order you want.

```
<input tabindex="3"> <input tabindex="1"> <input tabindex="2">
```

Quick demo: http://jsbin.com/cobecure/1

Answer (score 2):

Give them `tabIndex`, the element with the highest `tabIndex` will receive the focus last.  Which means your form element submit should have a `tabindex` value of greater than the `tabIndex`  value of input elements.

```
<h1 tabindex="-1" >Form</h1>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" tabindex="1">
      <input type="text"  tabindex="3">
      <input type="submit"  tabindex="2">

  </form>
```

**http://jsbin.com/reqin/2/edit**

Comment: It does the elements with tabindexes greater than 0 in order then goes through all the ones with 0 (the default value) in source order I think. So I'm not sure a high tab index on the last element is needed. Quick demo that suggests that: http://jsbin.com/cobecure/4/

Comment: form elements anyways will always Follows the platform convention of the element. tabIndex doesn't matter. However positive values specify the order of tabbing.

Comment: Understood, but it counts: 1, 2, 3, 4, 0. I was arguing the "Which means your form element submit should have a tabindex value of greater than the tabIndex value of input elements." part.